# Desenvolvendo um WebCrawler em Python

Tags: python, web-service, web-crawler

Existe algum projeto open source de **webcrawler** simples, desenvolvido em Python, para estudo?

Há algum tempo venho estudando / pesquisando sobre o assunto, mas não encontro nada pronto à respeito. Meu objetivo é estudar para criar um open source com as seguintes Features:

- Download do HTML de um link especifico
- Obtém o conteúdo de tags especificas, por exemplo: < p >, < h1 >
- Salva os conteúdos obtidos no banco de dados MySQL

Por isso gostaria de ter uma base de como desenvolver isso em Python de uma forma simples.
Caso vocês tenham uma ideia de como fazer (em código) por favor, me dá essa ajuda!

***obs:*** Meu domínio em Python atualmente é básico

Comment: [PyCrawler](https://github.com/theanti9/PyCrawler) para "crawlear", [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) para parsear HTML. A propósito, qual é exatamente a pergunta? Se é só se existe ou não uma ferramenta, receio que esteja fora de escopo. Do contrário, por favor especifique exatamente o que quer saber (de preferência, sem que a pergunta fique ampla demais e/ou baseada em opiniões).

Comment: editei a pergunta, meu objetivo é saber sobre webcrawlers open e caso alguem possa ajudar saber como posso desenvolver um de forma simples ... o objetivo seria para obter somente textos de links especificos

Comment: @GabrielMasson para criar um webcrawler de raiz tem aqui um tutorial: http://pythonprogramming.net/scraping-parsing-rss-feed/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Existem vários, pela minha experiência pessoal:

- [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) - para webscraping
- [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) - para webcrawling
- [sellenium webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/) - para automação de browser (quando mechanize não é capaz de lidar com o site, ex: ajax, ofuscação de código)

A instalação dos módulos é muito simples, na linha de comandos:

- pip install Scrapy ([documentação](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html))
- pip install mechanize ([tutorial](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/cheatsheet/python-mechanize-cheat-sheet))
- pip install selenium ([documentação](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/installation.html))

Comment: Esses projetos são todos muito legais e maduros -  e essenciais para usar em projetos grandes. Se o OP quiser só o resultado: o crawling e salvar os resultados, o Scrapy é a ferramenta mais apropriada. 

Se o objetivo for entender o código dos crawler, no entando, como o OP coloca, o scrapy é um projeto relativamente grande - eu diria que há espaço para mais uma resosta à esta pergunta focando nisso: um crawler simples, quer exemplificado na resposta, quer um projeto menor de crawler.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo estudar como a requisição é feita, cabeçalhos, response headers, user agent, entender bem como a transporte de dados acontece.

No momento de desenvolvimento, sempre debugar ao maxímo, tentar prever tudo, timeout, max requests, redirect, se algo der errado seu script tem que saber, e fazer o log.

recomendo estudar 
concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor para requisição assíncrona
junto com

threading.Thread para criar serviços de manutenção de banco de dados e tendencias, como quanto tempo o site levou para ser modificado, ajustando assim automaticamente o intervalo de requisições conforme a probabilidade de modificações no site

Recomento http://lxml.de/ junto com xpath e regex para extrair os dados

Espero que ajude em algo.